# How to build a wrapper on a class hierarchy?

Tags: c++

I have an existing class hierarchy. I want to write a wrapper on it, which renames the old classes and methods in the old classes. Is it possible to implement it? For example

```
class OldBase
{
public:
    void OldMethod();
};

class OldDerive : public OldBase
{
public:
    void OldMethod();
};
```

Replace "Old" names to "New" names but using the old existing implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of ways to do what you want, depending on your real needs.

1. The first (and probably worst) one is to use `#define` to rename your functions. It has a lot of flaws, but it can be fine, if your class hierarchy isn't big and you're not doing a big project using the wrapper.
2. You can also implement the wrapper as a `class`. And that's probably the best way.

   ```
    class wrapper{
    private:
       OldBase *base;
       wrapper(){base=0;};
    public:
       void newMethod();
       wrapper(OldBase* wrappedObject);
    };
   ```

Then you just do a wrapper by doing `wrapper myWrapper(&myBaseObj);`, and use it however you want. Of course you can also pass any derived class into the wrapper, or even design a constructor which takes a reference, instead of a pointer, and takes the address inside the constructor.